# WPF some images are rotated when loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF and cannot find some workaround. I have a basic image controll defined in XAML. I am loading bitmap images dynamically to this controll. The problem is that some of the bitmaps get flipped in the Image controll, when it's loaded and I want to load all images with it's default orientation.

This is my XAML:

```
<StackPanel Width="Auto" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="1,1,0,1" Orientation="Vertical" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GradientActiveCaptionBrushKey}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" >
   <Image x:Name="Photo"  Stretch="Uniform"  Height="149" Width="134" Margin="21,25,0,20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</StackPanel>
```

c# code:

```
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
img.BeginInit();
img.UriSource = new Uri(child.profilPoto.path, UriKind.Absolute);
img.EndInit();
Photo.Source = img;
```

thanks

**EDIT:**

Here is a link for image: [img](http://postimg.org/image/k2aownnm5/) On the left side there is a how the image is displayed in WPF. On the right side is original image.

**EDIT 2:**
[Original image](http://thewayur.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Csharp.jpg)

**SOLVED**
Thanks to all. It was metadata issue. I had a lot of photos with bad metadata. When i tried to load images from other camera it was ok. After saving broken images in some editor the photos loaded properly.

Comment: I dont see any problem with the above code.

Comment: I cant reproduce it with code. Can you show how original image different when viewed in WPF image control?

Comment: Is Any Scale Transform or any other transform applied to its parent?

Comment: Please post the original image file

Comment: I added picture to my question and edited XAML. @Sankarann - No transform is applied to it's parent.

Comment: @user2957509, this is not the original image, it's a screenshot of what you're seeing... I need to see the original file to see its metadata.

Comment: @Thomas Levesque, I added Original image.

Comment: @user2957509, I supected that the image specified a non-default orientation in its metadata, but it doesn't. I tried to display it in a WPF application, and it's displayed correctly (no rotation).

Comment: Maybe it's problem with my layout. I'll try to load image in new project and if it will be ok, then I'll modify my layout.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks to all. It was metadata issue. I had a lot of photos with bad metadata. When i tried to load images from other camera it was ok. After saving broken images in some editor the photos loaded properly.

Comment: You may want to delete the question, or edit it to say you've found the problem. (Your comment in which you say you've fixed it is actually so far down that it doesn't appear on screen by default - people have to click to see extra comments.) I just wasted 5 minutes attempting to repro this...

Answer (score 8):

Be cause BitmapMetadata,
This is my code,
And it works corectly

```
private static string _orientationQuery = "System.Photo.Orientation";
public static BitmapSource LoadImageFile(String path)
{
  Rotation rotation = Rotation.Rotate0;
  using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {
    BitmapFrame bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(fileStream, BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation, BitmapCacheOption.None);
    BitmapMetadata bitmapMetadata = bitmapFrame.Metadata as BitmapMetadata;

    if ((bitmapMetadata != null) && (bitmapMetadata.ContainsQuery(_orientationQuery)))
    {
      object o = bitmapMetadata.GetQuery(_orientationQuery);

      if (o != null)
      {
        switch ((ushort)o)
        {
          case 6:
            {
              rotation = Rotation.Rotate90;
            }
            break;
          case 3:
            {
              rotation = Rotation.Rotate180;
            }
            break;
          case 8:
            {
              rotation = Rotation.Rotate270;
            }
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  BitmapImage _image = new BitmapImage();
  _image.BeginInit();
  _image.UriSource = new Uri(path);
  _image.Rotation = rotation;
  _image.EndInit();
  _image.Freeze();

  return _image;
}
```

Comment: This is elegant and perfect. Thank you. (Where the "System.Photo.Orientation" query comes form? is there any documentation).

Comment: Here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-photo-orientation