# C# WPF when image is loaded the width and height are switched

Tags: c#, wpf, image

In WPF c# loading an image from code in runtime, some images are loading when the width and height are switched so the width=height and height=width so the image is turned in 90 degrees.
In the file system properties tab, the Width and Height are correct and the image is shown correctly. If I open this image in any imageViewer the image is shown correctly but if I open it in powerpoint the same issue is found and the image is turned. 
I downloaded some other codes in WPF and all are showing the image turned.
most images are shown correctly.

For example This Image :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5fki0ew3gt78myi/TestImage_Widht4000_Height6000.JPG?dl=0

The Widht=4000and Height=6000 but if I get the bitmap.PixelWidth=6000 and bitmap.PixelHeight=400

Can anyone please help!
Thanks

I have tried everything :(

```
           var ImagefilePath = SelectedImagePath + "\\" + ((object[])(e.AddedItems))[0].ToString();

            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(ImagefilePath.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute);

            bitmap.EndInit();

            // Set Image.Source  
            imgPhoto.Source = bitmap;

            ImageInfoText.Content=" W=" + bitmap.PixelWidth + " H=" + bitmap.PixelHeight;
```

Comment: Can you show the XAML?

Comment: I found that if I download the file from the link dropbox will fix the image so please try using the image from this link :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/axcv5ym9cyxp0l1/TestImage_Widht4000_Height6000.zip?dl=0

Comment: please insert the images directly to you post. The dropbox link might vanish in future. The picture in the question will remain.

Comment: As a note, you can simplify your code to `var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImagefilePath, UriKind.Absolute));`. No need for Begin/EndInit when you only set the source Uri.

Comment: I can't add the image because when I upload the image it solve the issue and if you download the image the problem is fixed (something is changing in the coding of the image)

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably the metadata within the image itself. You need to get rid of the metadata and that should fix your problem.

Here is a similar issue : [WPF some images are rotated when loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848861/wpf-some-images-are-rotated-when-loaded)

Here is how you can remove metadata: [Easy way to clean metadata from an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586699/easy-way-to-clean-metadata-from-an-image)

The preferable way would be to use the `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapEncoder` class's `Metadata` collection property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still didn't manage to use the codes in the links you attached in your answer and the similar issue was not solved (he used outside app to convert the image to solve the issue and it will not work for me because I need to load images at runtime like viewer)

Answer (score 0):

Usually one gets this kind of problem when taking pictures/videos with mobile phones. They report the size of the sensor, regardless how the phone is hold (in landscape or portrait). These files contain also metadata, indicating if the phone was turned by 90 degrees. Windows File Explorer uses this metadata and switches width and height if the phone was turned. So from the File Explorer you get the impression that the Height and Width change in Landscape and Portrait mode. But they don't. Unfortunately, WPF is a bit outdated and just believes height and width reported by the phone.

An example of the metadata of a mp4 file:

```
Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661),
yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 3840x2160, 71957 kb/s, 32.24 fps,
        29.83 tbr, 90k tbn (default)
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2023-08-05T09:04:15.000000Z
    handler_name    : VideoHandle
    vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Side data:
    displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
```

The information that the phone was turned by 90 degrees is in the last line.

Meaning you have to read the metadata of that file. This can be done by using a library like TagLib:

```
var fileProperties = TagLib.File.Create(startFile.FullName);
var tagLibTag = (TagLib.Image.CombinedImageTag)fileProperties.Tag;
var rotation = tagLibTag.Orientation switch {
  TagLib.Image.ImageOrientation.None => Rotation.Rotate0,
  TagLib.Image.ImageOrientation.TopLeft => Rotation.Rotate0,
  TagLib.Image.ImageOrientation.BottomRight => Rotation.Rotate180,
  TagLib.Image.ImageOrientation.RightTop => Rotation.Rotate90,
  TagLib.Image.ImageOrientation.LeftBottom => Rotation.Rotate270, //
  _ => throw new NotSupportedException(),
};
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(startFile.FullName);
bitmap.Rotation = rotation;
bitmap.EndInit();
PictureViewer.Source = bitmap;
```

Unfortunately, Taglib does not work for mp4 files. But there are other libraries.

Please read my article on codeproject WPF: [Displaying Photos and Videos Properly in Portrait and Landscape orientation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5368802/WPF-Displaying-Photos-and-Videos-Properly-in-Portr) for more detailed explanation and code for mp4 file processing.